# How inline styles are added automatically while using jquery isotope? How to remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have searched it . I found some links .. But none of them helps me .

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974594/jquery-isotope-plugin-adding-inline-displaynone-cant-figure-out-why
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404933/jquery-isotope-library-with-html-tables

<div class="menu filter_open">
                       <span class="filter_by">
                        <em>Filter Awards By :</em>
                       </span>
                       <span data-filter="country_filter" class="drop-down">
                            Country
                       </span>
                       <span data-filter="continent_filter" class="drop-down">
                            Continent
                       </span>
                       <span data-filter="test_filter" class="drop-down">
                            Test
                       </span>
                       <span data-filter="odi_filter" class="drop-down">
                            ODI
                       </span>
                       <span data-filter="t20_filter" class="drop-down">
                            T20
                       </span>
                      </div>
<div class="filter_open filter_open2">
                    <div id="country_filter" class="filters">
                        <p>ghfgh</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="continent_filter" class="filters">
                            <p>zxzcxzc</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="test_filter" class="filters">
                            <p>zxczxcz</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="odi_filter" class="filters">
                        <p>zxczxcxz</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="t20_filter" class="filters">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

My javascript code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var container = $('.filter_open');
 $('.filter_open span.drop-down').click(function(){

    var selector ='#'+ $(this).attr('data-filter');
    container.isotope({
        filter: selector
     });
     return false;
 }); 
 });
```

Necessary CSS are:

```
.filter_open2
{

    width:100%;
    height:4%;
    border:1px solid;
} 
.filters
{
display:none;
}

.isotope-item {
  z-index: 2;
}

.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
 pointer-events: none;
 z-index: 1;
 }
```

When i click on country , it should show only the div element that matches with country_filter.. But when i click on a particular filter , everything will be disappeared. When i try to debug it using firebug , i figured out that inline styles are added automatically.. Why it is added automatically? How to solve this problem? Can you please help me?!
[This is the image before i click on a filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEU5x.png)!
[This is the picture after i click on country and the below part shows the inline styles that are added automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8Cmo.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setAttribute("style","");` on the element after jquery isotope has finished adding inline styles to it.

*Example for an element with any Id:*

```
document.getElementById('#Id').setAttribute("style",""); // For any element Id
```

---

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/25VUY/)**.It affects only inline styles.

---

## Updated:

**Try the following code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 var container = $('.filter_open');
 $('.filter_open span.drop-down').click(function(){

    var selector ='#'+ $(this).attr('data-filter');
    container.isotope({
        filter: selector
    });

     var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down");

     for(i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
     {
     ele[i].setAttribute("style","");
     }
     return false;
  }); 
  });
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/25VUY/6/)

Comment: ,if i add document,getElementsByClass(".drop-down").setAttribute("style",""); , won't it override the other styles that i added to the class drop-down?

Comment: It will affect only inline styles

Comment: Your `document.getElementsByClass` is wrong.Write it like `document.getElementsByClassName("drop-down")[0].setAttribute("style","");` . Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/25VUY/3/

Comment: i have added the following code.                                                                          var ele=document.getElementsByClassName(".drop-down");
   for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
   {
   ele.setAttribute("style","");
   }

Comment: Yes , I checked that fiddle .. It affects only that .. I have doubt , i am using isotope from this site [link](http://www.9bitstudios.com/demos/blog/jquery-isotope/js/jquery.isotope.js) .. Whether it causes that problem?

Comment: Again your code is wrong .Change it to  `var ele=document.getElementsByClassName(".drop-down"); for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++) { ele[i].setAttribute("style",""); } `

Comment: Output with your code which misses `e[i] within for loop` :http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/25VUY/5/ .Corrected fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/25VUY/6/